# Bash: loop through file line by line, find specific string and append to each subsequent line until same string is found

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk, grep

I typically work with raw or csv files that have unique identifiers I can use within various math programmes.  Recently I was given a folder of files where the only way of matching records to each other is by the position they hold within the text file.

Here is an example File01.txt:

```
AA1000   
AA2222        
AB1X6110305126101234760ABA08B88                   ZZ1111110000  
AB2X611030512612006100901C109Z 001110001110                                    
AB2X611030512612006100901X571Z 007410000000                                                                   
AB1X6110305127101234760ABA10B89                   ZZ1111110022  
AB2X611030512712006101001A571Z 007410000000                                  
AB1X6110305128101234760ABA10C00                   ZZ1111110055  
AB2X611030512812006101001A571Z 007410007410                                    
AC11
```

Line 3 begins with AB1 and Lines 4-8 begin with AB2 and correspond to Line 3 as indicated by the 12 character string starting at position 4 of the line.  That 12 character string is the only way to match clusters but it is not necessarily unique across all lines.  The only way to know the AB2 groups in 4-8 correspond to the AB1 group in Line 3 is that lines 4-8 follow line 3.  For a non-programmer like me, this is a nightmare.

What I would like to do is read in File01.txt and loop through line by line until it hits an AB1 line.  I want to store the AB1 line and then continue looping through.  An AB1 line is always followed by at least one AB2 line.  I would like to write the AB2 line to an array and append the AB1 line from memory and continue looping and writing to the array until a new AB1 line is encountered.  The new AB1 line will now be stored in memory and do as above until the next AB1 line and so on and so forth until it reaches the end of the file (typically an AC11 line)

The output file, I hope, could then look like this:

```
AB2X611030512612006100901C109Z 001110001110    AB1X6110305126101234760ABA08B88                   ZZ1111110000                            
AB2X611030512612006100901X571Z 007410000000    AB1X6110305126101234760ABA08B88                   ZZ1111110000                                                         
AB2X611030512712006101001A571Z 007410000000    AB1X6110305127101234760ABA10B89                   ZZ1111110022                                 
AB2X611030512812006101001A571Z 007410007410    AB1X6110305128101234760ABA10C00                   ZZ1111110055
```

Although not ideal, I can work with that type of data and split the strings etc.  Is this possible using something like bash and awk or sed or something of the sort?

Thank you in advance for any help/insight one might provide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have your requirements right, this little awk program will work:

```
awk '/^AB1/{ab1=$0;next}/^AB2/{print $0, ab1}'
```

That will do nothing with any line which doesn't start with AB1 or AB2 and it fails to check for equality of the 12-character string following the AB1/AB2. I couldn't tell if you require that check.

Comment: Thank you for trying to lend a hand.  Sorry I wasn't clear about needing the check.  I don't.  I just need to be able to run some command that will eat through the text files creating new ones with the information list.  How would I run this awk command?  awk file01.txt then the command above and pipe that to a new file?

Comment: @FocusedEnergy: then that command should work (you need to add the filename, of course: awk '/...}' file01.txt

Comment: Thank you rici.  I think I am very close.  I ran the command and the output file has an AB2 line followed by an AB1 line.  Is it possible to print $0 on the same line as AB2 so it would be imported as one row of data?

Comment: `$0` is the AB2 line, and `print $0, ab1` does not introduce a newline character. Possibly you are seeing a linebreak because the line is too long for your terminal? Normally, awk puts a tab between the arguments to `print`; if you would prefer something else, you can write, for example: `print $0 " " ab1` or `print $0 " | " ab1`

Comment: Hi rici, thank you again for your follow-up.  I changed the delimiter and it still appears on separate lines.  I must have something in the file I can't make out (or the multiple spaces is breaking something).  The example I provided above is the exact spacing.  If I copy that output and run your awk command, I always end up with the AB1 line following the AB2 line but never on the same line.  Is there a way to force a concatenation?  From my understanding the "," does just that, so it should be working as you wrote it.

Comment: @FocusedEnergy: There are a lot of spaces at the ends of those lines. Are you sure that the output really has separate lines? I think it's quite likely that whatever you're using to view the file is splitting the lines so that you can see them. Try piping the command through `wc` to see what the actual line count is.

Comment: @FocusedEnergy: By the way, if the AB2 lines always have two fields (as in your example), then you could try: `print $1, $2, ab1` and see if that looks better. That will trim out all the excess spaces.

Comment: Hi rici, this worked!  I have no idea what the $0 was doing to pump the ab1 to a new line, but the above print command worked like a charm.  As a final request for help, is it trivial to grab the file name and add it to the print command so that the file name becomes a new variable on import (so I can track where we got the data from).  Thank you very much for all your help.  Steep learning curve for me, but in the last 24 hours I've certainly improved from 0% to maybe 1.1% :)

Comment: The variable `FILENAME` contains the current filename (surprise!). You can put more than one file on the command line, and awk will then do them in order.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/^AB1/!d;$!N;/\nAB2/!D;s/\s+$/ /;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\1\n\1/;P;D' file
```

The spacing in the example provided seems a little irractic, so I reduced it to a single space.

Comment: Thank you potong.  I am on a Mac, running BSD sed, the "-r" doesn't seem to work at all.  I think you are right, the spacing is likely causing problems (and it is what I am starting with) and if I can deal with the spacing, hopefully I can get these lines joined up.  Someone many years ago was not thinking.  No unique identifier in this type of data?  Craziness! :)