# Loop through text file & find strings to append to children strings in hierarchically related text file

Tags: java, macos, perl, awk

I have number of text files containing hierarchically related strings.

**Edit** Here is an example. The files look essentially as below

```
HEBV000000000000
HEH11111111  2222222022HCPP      3333        0000 AAA
HET11111  22222222222222
HEH888888  3333333333HCPP      3333        0000 AAA
HET2222  33333333333333333
HEH44444444 55555555HCPP      4444      0000 BBB
HET555555  0066666666666666666
HEE0019000000090
HEBV0120150301429
HEH5588558888 5555000044440000NCPP       164201503010000 HIP
HER9999A 0157000120150303333
HET8888B 0036400120150303333
HEE0044000000040
```

The breakdown is:

```
HEB (start of batch1)
HEH (start of group1)
HET (end of group1)
HEH (start of group2)
HET (end of group2)
HEH (start of group3)
HET (end of group3)
HEE (end of batch1)
HEB (start of batch 2)
HEH (start of group1)
HER (start of subgroup1)
HET (end of group1)
HEE (end of batch2)
```

The strings are related in a few ways:

HEB string denotes the beginning of a batch. HEE details the number of HEH, HER and HET records in the preceding batch.

The next relationship is the meat of the document and that is HER and HET records are related to a single HEH. Batches (HEB to HEE) can contain multiple HEH-HER-HET groups. There will always be at least one HEH-HET group in a batch; an there may be many. If an HER record is present it is related to the HEH preceding it and all HETs following it until a new HER or HEH is encountered. So HER and HET records are only ever related to a single HEH record but an HEH record can be associated with multiple HER and HET records.

There is no linking identifier in any of the strings. The only usable relationship then is the position of the string in the file. (Not my doing and I can't change this)

What I would like to do is have an output file that would be based on HET records and look like the following so that I might import into a statistics package (Note that I mean to print the entire string from each line but for ease of reading I am just showing the HE* of the strings):

```
HET1 HEH1 HEB FILENAME HEE
HET2 HEH2 HER2 HEB FILENAME HEE
HET3 HEH3 HER3 HEB FILENAME HEE
```

and so on.

My logic for how I think it would work is:

```
Read in the file
Get filename and append to HEB records

Then
Look for HEB record and store
Look for HEE record and store
Append HEB and HEE to HEH
  if new HEB is found repeat above until end of file

Then

Look for HEH record and store
Append to HET records until an HEH or HEE record is found
if a new HEH is found, append it to HET records until HEH or HEE is found
repeat until eof

Then

Look for HER record and store
Append to HET records until an HER, HEH or HEE record is found
if a new HER is found, append it to HET records until an HER, HEH or HEE record is found
repeat until eof
save to new file
```

I think that would get me to the

```
HET1 HEH1 HEB FILENAME HEE
HET2 HEH2 HER2 HEB FILENAME HEE
HET3 HEH3 HER3 HEB FILENAME HEE
```

I previously asked similar questions with files of a similar format:

[*Bash: loop through file line by line, find specific string and append to each subsequent line until same string is found*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915200/bash-loop-through-file-line-by-line-find-specific-string-and-append-to-each-su)

and

[*bash & awk: Loop through dir running two separate awk commands on all files and saving in new dir*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934728/bash-awk-loop-through-dir-running-two-separate-awk-commands-on-all-files-and)

Unfortunately, these files are more complex because of the multi-tiered relationship. This goes beyond my ability to modify the solution from those other questions

code:

```bash
for f in *txt
do
    awk '/^AB1/{ab1=$0;next}/^AB2/{print $1, $2, ab1}' "$f" > "new$f"
    awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,FILENAME}' "new$f" > "newnew$f"
done
```

I don't know if awk is a good idea here, or if something like Perl or Java would be better. As I mentioned in those other questions, I'm a physician, not a programmer, and although I can modify code with some understanding (usually tripping over my feet), when I encounter something like this, I find myself far out of my depth.

Comment: I'd do it in `perl` myself - but I'm also having difficulty following your question. Can you give some sample (sanitised) input and desired output?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  The file looks like the first block in the question, that is:`HEB row then HEH row then HET row, the strings are longer but the start of each line is an HEB, HEH, HER, HET or HEE.  That's it, all the way through the file.

Comment: *"an HEH record can be associated with multiple HER and HET records."* Are you certain of this? The data format makes much more sense if the HEH and HET records are paired in the same way as the HEB and HEE records. I can understand that there may be multiple HER records, in a sequence such as HEH HER HER HER HET, but you're saying that there may also be multiple HET records, as in HEH HER HET HER HET HER HER HET

Comment: As [Sobrique has asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358004/loop-through-text-file-find-strings-to-append-to-children-strings-in-hierarchi/36364336#comment60336248_36358004), *"Can you give some sample (sanitised) input and desired output?"* An example is worth a lot of words, and it would help enormously to see the exact output that you expect from your sample input

Comment: The first batch of code is an actual file output save for some changes with numbers and letters to desensitize it.  The HEB is the batch header.  The HEE is the batch footer.  An HER is absolutely associated with the preceding HEH and an HER ALWAYS follows an HEH if it appears.  Typically only HEH and HET records appear in a batch but the rare occasion of an HER record simply adds more information to that particularly HEH.  The HEH is an account specification string.  The HET records are items falling under the HEH that came before it/them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do as you wish, but your description is a little opaque

- The program keeps track of the values of the most recent HEB and HEH records, and all HER records since the previous HEH or HET
- I've used the first field of each line in the input file. It's unclear whether this is enough or if you need the data in the entire line
- The contents of an output record are saved in array `@records` at whenever an HET is encountered, but at this point they are missing the HEE information so cannot be printed yet
- At every HEE record, all waiting output is printed together with the value of the current record, and the waiting list is emptied
- Note that I've altered the input slightly from your own example to allow for multiple HET records per HEH, and multiple HER records per HET
- The line `@ARGV = 'f1.txt'` emulates a parameter on the command line, and it is as if you entered `perl process_data.pl f1.txt`. You should remove this line before using the code, and the intended method is to use a glob pattern for a parameter so that the shell will find all relevant files and pass them to the code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'state';

@ARGV = 'f1.txt';

my ( $heb, $heh, @her );

my @records;

while ( <> ) {

    my ($item) = split;

    die unless my ($type) = $item =~ /^(HE[BHRTE])/;

    state $dispatch = {
        HEB => sub {
            $heb = shift;
            $heh = undef;
            @her = ();
        },
        HEH => sub {
            $heh = shift;
            @her = ();
        },
        HER => sub {
            push @her, shift;
        },
        HET => sub {
            my $het      = shift;
            my $filename = $ARGV;
            push @records, [ $het, $heh, @her, $heb, $filename ];
            @her = ();
        },
        HEE => sub {

            my $hee = shift;

            for my $rec (@records) {
                push @$rec, $hee;
                print "@$rec\n";
            }

            $heb = $heh = undef;
            @her = ();
            @records = ();
        },
    };

    $dispatch->{$type}->($item);
}
```

#### input

```
HEBV000000000000
HEH11111111  2222222022HCPP      3333        0000 AAA
HET11111  22222222222222
HEH888888  3333333333HCPP      3333        0000 AAA
HET2222  33333333333333333
HEH44444444 55555555HCPP      4444      0000 BBB
HET555555  0066666666666666666
HEE0019000000090
HEBV0120150301429
HEH5588558888 5555000044440000NCPP       164201503010000 HIP
HER9999A 0157000120150303333
HER9999B 0157000120150303333
HET8888B 0036400120150303333
HER9999C 0157000120150303333
HER9999D 0157000120150303333
HET8888B 0036400120150303333
HEE0044000000040
```

#### output

```
HET11111 HEH11111111 HEBV000000000000 f1.txt HEE0019000000090
HET2222 HEH888888 HEBV000000000000 f1.txt HEE0019000000090
HET555555 HEH44444444 HEBV000000000000 f1.txt HEE0019000000090
HET8888B HEH5588558888 HER9999A HER9999B HEBV0120150301429 f1.txt HEE0044000000040
HET8888B HEH5588558888 HER9999C HER9999D HEBV0120150301429 f1.txt HEE0044000000040
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to stick with this question.  Your output looks perfect.  I am going to try it and will report back.  Many thanks.

Comment: This is perfect.  Thank you very much.  Can I replace @ARGV with something akin to a `for f in *.txt  do hfile.pl "$f" > "new$f"'?  I'll have to work out the perl syntax.  That is how I would run something using awk.

Comment: @FocusedEnergy: That's what I meant by my last bullet point. You can get the shell to expand the list of files for you if you use `perl process_data.pl *.txt`. That way you can change which files are being processed without editing the program. Note that you *must* remove the `@ARGV = ` line though, otherwise it will override anything passed on the command line. If you really want to do it in the code then you would change it to `@ARGV = glob '*.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not entirely clear what your file *actually* looks like - but you can do this more easily if you *don't* focus on line-by-line processing.

There's two tricks in particular - the first setting a record separator using `$/` and reading your file in chunks.

So e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = 'HEE'; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
    print "\nStart of Record\n";
    print;
   print "\nEnd of Record\n";
}

__DATA__
HEB (start of batch1)                       
HEH (start of group1)     
HET                                      
HET                                               
HET (end of group1)                                                                                                                               
HEH (start of group2)
HET
HET (end of group2)
HEE (end of batch1)
```

This will run through the loop each time it hits a 'HEB' marker in your file. At which point, you can apply a regex match to extract sub elements. So looking at it - HEH separates subrecords:

```
 my @groups = m/^(HEH .*?(?=HE[HE]))/gms;
   foreach my $group ( @groups ) { 
        print "Start of group:\n";
        print $group;
        print "End of group\n";
   }
```

This uses regular expressions and zero-width patterns to capture chunks of text between 'HEH' and 'HEH' or 'HEE' giving:

```
Start of group:
HEH (start of group1)     
HET                                      
HET                                               
HET (end of group1)                                                                                                                               
End of group
Start of group:
HEH (start of group2)
HET
HET (end of group2)
End of group
```

And combining these two techniques, you should be able to select the things you want into your record. I'm afraid I can't give you a more detailed example, because I'd really need a more complete example input and output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = 'HEE'; 

while ( <DATA> ) {
    print "\nStart of Record\n";
    print;
   print "\nEnd of Record\n";

   my @groups = m/^(HEH .*?(?=HE[HE]))/gms;
   foreach my $group ( @groups ) { 
        print "Start of group:\n";
        print $group;
        print "End of group\n";
        my @HET = $group =~ m/HET (.*)$/gm; 
        print "HET lines: \n";
        print join "\n", @HET,"\n";
   }
}

__DATA__
HEB (start of batch1)                       
HEH (start of group1)     
HET                                      
HET                                               
HET (end of group1)                                                                                                                               
HEH (start of group2)
HET
HET (end of group2)
HEE (end of batch1)
HEB (start of batch 2)
HEH (start of group1)            
HER (start of subgroup1)                                
HET                                     
HET                                                
HER (start of subgroup2)                                     
HET                                            
HEH (start of group2)                               
HET (end of group2)                              
HEE (end of batch 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response.  I have edited my original question to show an actual example of the text file and I will try working with your suggestions to see if I can get it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Admitting not understanding this format and purpose (and the mindset of the person who came up with this) and assuming it has consistent structure, this may work

```
$ awk '/HER/{r++;m=0} 
      !m&&/HET/{m++; t++; 
        print $1 t, "HEH" t, (r?"HER"t OFS:"") "HEB", FILENAME, "HEE";next}' heb

HET1 HEH1 HEB heb HEE
HET2 HEH2 HER2 HEB heb HEE
HET3 HEH3 HER3 HEB heb HEE
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I will test out your suggestion.  The format is consistent in that the each line in the file starts with an HE*.  The strings are longer, but they always start that way.  I want to suck the final file up so I can use it in a stats program.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do  this with awk:

```
gawk -v RS="HEB" '{
    for(i=2;i<NF;i++){
        if( $i ~ /^HE[R|H]/){
            x=x" "$i
        };
        if( $i ~ /^HET/ ){
            print $i""x,"HEB"$1,FILENAME,$NF;x=""
        }
    }
}' file.txt
```